# Local notification when my data in coredata are updated?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have an application that  retrieve data from website and seva in to core data by checking the predicate that the data is exist or not. If not save in to core data. if Yes update the old one. I need to make an local notification when new data is inserted. Can I do that? Any idea?

Many Thanks

Comment: here you can put the condition that if data or record is not exist then fire the LocalNotification its simple... but what you want please clear your que.

Comment: I am new to local notification. I don't know how to fire the local notification in my add method.

Comment: ok ok mate i post code for LocanNotification see

Comment: hey insted of LocalNotificaltion, you can use UIAlertView because here UIAlertView is enough fot your requirement... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fire notification at current time using

`localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];`

Follow apple documentation for local nonfiction [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Sample code for localNotification [Link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

**My Code**

```
-(IBAction)localNotificationBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (!localNotification) 
        return;

    // Current date
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 


    // Add one minute to the current time
    NSDate *dateToFire = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];

    NSLog(@"local noti fire date...>> %@",dateToFire);

    // Set the fire date/time
    [localNotification setFireDate:dateToFire];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    // Setup alert notification
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Notification hiiiiiiiiiiiiii" ];
    localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];      

    UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];

     [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (newRecord)
{
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {
        NSString *kRemindMeNotificationDataKey = @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey";

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[cls alloc] init];

        notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Record Inserted"];
        notification.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:yourObjectorString forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notification.userInfo = userDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        [notification release];
    }
}
```

i hope this help you..

:)

Comment: also if your app is running at that time local notification not appear so at the time of firedate your this app must closed

Comment: Thanks for your post. For working with the add method. I need to register the notification in DidEnterBackground or init method?

Comment: what?? for which init method??

Comment: sorry for my English. I just want to know how this method will call for notification.

Comment: it automatically call, here we add notification after on its fire date , its call automatically appear by iPhone we not required to call manually :)

Comment: no when you close application then its call with its fire date means if your notification time is 4PM then at that time your application must closed..